# Give an example of $\phi$ and $\psi$ : $\forall x$ $\phi$ $\equiv$ $\forall$ $x$ $\psi$, but $\phi$ $\not\equiv$ $\psi$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Give an example of $\phi$ and $\psi$ :  $\forall x$$\phi$ $\equiv$$\forall$$\psi$, but  $\phi$$\not\equiv$$\psi$

I think it's about $\exists$ $x$ predicat, but i'm not sure.

Comment: What is the language $\mathcal L$ of your sentences?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net . We can use &, "or", "->", "=", $\exists$, $\forall$ and xor

Comment: I believe @mathcounterexamples.net is asking about the **non-logical** symbols - also called the *signature* or *vocabulary*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is indeed what I was asking for. And if I understand well, this is called *signature* or *vocabulary* in English. I was using the improper translation of the French *langage*.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net "Signature," "language," and "vocabulary" are all standard. "Similarity type" is older, but still appears occasionally. We have way too many words for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in a language with two constant symbols $c$ and $d$: we set $$\phi(x): x=c\quad\mbox{and}\quad\psi(x): x=d.$$ Clearly $\phi\not\equiv\psi$ in general: in any structure where the symbols $c$ and $d$ are interpreted differently, $\phi$ and $\psi$ will in turn mean different things. However, the sentences "$\forall x\phi(x)$" and "$\forall x\psi(x)$" are much simpler: each sentence is true in a given structure $\mathcal{M}$ if and only if

> that structure has exactly one element.